# Video-JS Prevent click event from propagationinig to child elements

Tags: jquery, video, plugins

I created a simple video page with Video-JS plugin. videos plays in a popup module. What i'm trying to do is to close this popup whenever the video wrapper is clicked, not the video. But i fail to do so and even when i click on video controls the popup closes. My code looks like this:

```
$('.popup-video').click(function() {
    $(this).fadeOut(500);
    // Pause Video
});
$('.popup-video>div').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
$('.popup-video>video').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

`.stopPropagation` method used to do the trick, but not now! what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Any errors on the console?

Comment: @undefined no nothing.

Comment: @NOjAN try `e.cancelBubble = true;`

Comment: Did you try [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/FKHu3/)

Comment: @adeneo thank you so much. it worked. please write an answer so i can choose it as correct one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just check if the clicked element (event target) is in fact the element referenced in the event handler (this), and only do the fading if it is. That would avoid issues with clicks propagating from children elements and firing the function :

```
$('.popup-video').click(function(e) {
    if (e.target === this) $(this).fadeOut(500);
});
```